# Text file read only is not working in java temp.setReadonly() is not working

Tags: java, spring

```
 package com.studytrails.tutorials.springremotingrmiserver;
        import java.lang.Object;
        import java.io.*;
        import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

        import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
        import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

        public class GreetingServiceImpl implements GreetingService {
            @Override
            public String getGreeting(String name) {

                return "Hello " + name + "!";

            }


               public String getText()
               {
                   ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"spring-config-server.xml"});

            Resource resource = appContext.getResource("file:D:\\text\\test.txt");
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        try{

              InputStream is = resource.getInputStream();
              BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
              File temp=File.createTempFile("output", ".tmp");
              temp.setReadOnly();
              String filePath=temp.getAbsolutePath();
             // System.out.println(""+filePath);


              String line;
              PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("temp"));

              while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
               //System.out.println(line);

                  out.println(line);


                  //br.close();
              }

              RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(temp, "r");
              String[] cmd = {"notepad" , "temp"}; 
              Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

              Process proc = runtime.exec(cmd);

              out.close();
              br.close();

         temp.deleteOnExit();

            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return builder.toString();

               }


            }
```

In this code `temp.setReadonly()` method is not working it opens the file with all access
    how can i control the temp file access.please verify it and give me the idea 
how can i solve it. here i am trying to open the file in read only mode which is located in 
temporary path but the code opens the text document but it not in read only mode. how can i change it

Comment: R u sure that File temp is created ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is wrong

1. You are opening a file called `output.tmp` and setting that to read only
2. You are writing to a file called `temp`
3. You are forcing notepad to open with the file written in 2 not the file created in step 1

The file opened in step 1 is read-only but it isn't used in the remainder of the code, which operates on an entirly different file.

Another tip never construct an `ApplicationContext` yourself, unless it is for bootstrapping your application. Either implement `ApplicationContextAware` or create a instance variable to hold the `ApplicationContext` and put `@Autowired` on it.